# Flac samples calculation

Tags: audio, cue-sheet

I have a cuesheet from EAC and a FLAC file with the full album in.
Im trying to make a little python script to play the file, there for i need to be able to set the position where to start in the flac file.

How do i get from the CueSheet format MM:SS:FF to samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each minute contains 60 seconds (obviously); each second contains 75 frames; and each frame contains 588 samples.

So the calculation would be something like this...

```
offset = ((((minutes * 60) + seconds) * 75) + frames) * 588
```

Comment: I think this calculation is slightly off- it should be `((((60 * minutes) + seconds) * 75) + frames) * 588`

Comment: @sbooth: Thanks, you're right. I can't believe that this answer has been sitting here for almost a year without me -- or anybody else -- noticing that the calculation was off. I've edited to fix.