# splitting a flac image into tracks

Tags: audio, lossless, cue-sheet

This is a follow up question to [Flac samples calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728632/flac-samples-calculation).

Do I implement the offset generated by that formula from the beginning of the file or after the metadata where the stream starts ([here](http://flac.sourceforge.net/format.html#frame))?

My goal is to programmatically divide the file myself - largely as a learning exercise. My thought is that I would write down my flac header and metadata blocks based on values learned from the image and then the actual track I get from the master image using my cuesheet.

Currently in my code I can parse each metadata block and end up where the frames start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are trying to decode starting at `M:S.F = 3:45.30`.  There are 75 frames (CDDA sectors) per second, and obviously there are 60 seconds per minute.  To convert M:S.F from your cue sheet into a sample offset value, I would first calculate the number of CDDA sectors to the desired starting point: `(((60 * 3) + 45) * 75) + 30 = 16,905`.  Since there are 75 sectors per second, assuming the audio is sampled at 44,100 Hz there are `44,100 / 75 = 588` audio samples per sector.  So the desired audio sample offset where you will start decoding is `588 * 16,905 = 9,940,140`.

The offset just calculated is an offset into the decompressed PCM samples, not into the compressed FLAC stream (nor in bytes).  So for each FLAC frame, calculate the number of samples it contains and keep a running tally of your position. Skip FLAC frames until you find the one containing your starting audio sample.  At this point you can start decoding the audio, throwing away any samples in the FLAC frame that you don't need.

FLAC also supports a `SEEKTABLE` block, the use of which would greatly speed up (and alter) the process I just described.  If you haven't already you can look at the implementation of the [reference decoder](http://flac.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flac/flac/src/libFLAC/stream_decoder.c?view=markup).

Comment: OK. Thanks. This has definitely helped. Now whats got me scratching my head is the "UTF-8" coded frame number in the frame header (as in decoding it). But I still need to review the link you gave me on the reference decoder.